# Batch file - splitting a default gate way in to it's component parts, adding a number then reconstituting

Tags: ip, gateway

Basically, what I need to do is get the default gateway of a Win7 machine which I have accomplished with the below code:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 delims={}, " %%A in ('wmic nicconfig get defaultIPgateway') do for /f "tokens=1" %%B in ("%%~A") do set "IP=%%~B"
echo %IP%
```

Trouble is, what I need to do then, is pull the last part (so from `10.10.10.1`, I need the `1`, check it's either `1`,`65`,`83` or `192`) add a number to it then reconstitute it back to a full IP - eg. `10.10.10.2`

I'm stuck at the splitting part...

I've got:

```
FOR /F "DELIMS=. TOKENS=4" %a IN %%IP%% DO ECHO %d
```

What am I doing wrong?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: FOR /F "TOKENS=4 DELIMS=. " %%f IN ("%IP%") DO ECHO %%f

This seems to have gotten me the 2, so getting close...

Comment: If the code in your latest comment is getting you the last octet ("2" from 10.1.1.2 I assume you mean), then I'm not sure what's left in your question to answer?

Comment: Yes I think I ended up answering my own question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I get the last octet from the default gateway IP address?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem throw away everything except the ip address line 
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`wmic nicconfig get defaultIPgateway ^| findstr "{"`) do (
  rem we have for example {"192.168.42.129"}
  rem split on " and get 2nd token
  for /f delims^=^"^ tokens^=2 %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
     rem we have 192.168.42.129
     rem split on . and get 4 tokens (octets)
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%c in ("%%b") do (
      rem we have 129
      set _o1=%%c
      set _o2=%%d
      set _o3=%%e
      set _o4=%%f
      )
    )
  )
echo %_o4%
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.